# Bootstrap responsive - styles under 480px don't work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to reduce the size of my title for smart phones.

The title is styled as follows in my style.css:

```
.hero-unit h3{
    font-size:48px;
    font-weight:500;
    margin:20px 0;
}
```

Under `@media (max-width: 480px)` I want the title size to be 30px and margin to be 10px, so I added

```
.hero_unit h3{
    font-size:30px !important;
    margin:10px 0 !important;
  }
```

The `!important` bit is to make sure the attributes aren't overwritten by the ones in style.css. But still, the styles aren't applied when I open the site on my smartphone, or reduce the windows size below 480px on my laptop.

When I click 'inspect element', the only styles attached to the `h3` (apart from inherited ones) are the ones from style.css. Can't see the others, not even crossed out.

Any ideas what the problem is and how to resolve it?

Comment: try changing width of the window of your browser on your computer. Do the changes apply?

Comment: Is it possible to see the normal css, is it using exactly the same selector .hero-unit h3 I mean there isn't an id before it, or suchlike?

Comment: Or maybe you could post a jsfiddle.

Comment: One thing you have .hero-unit in the main css and .hero_unit in the media query css

Comment: I have had similar issues using max-width, instead try using max-device-width min-device-width

Comment: @lharby There's no ID on the h3. I've posted all relevant CSS, I've checked multiple times that there's nothing else affecting the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment my guess is that your main css writes:

```
.hero-unit h3 {}
```

But your media query css writes

```
.hero_unit h3 {}
```

If this is correct you shouldn't then need to use !important;

Comment: The number of times I have pulled my hair out, when I just left a semi-colon off the end

Answer (score 1):

In these codes , Your selector have problem
.hero-unit is different from .hero_unit !!! isn't it ?